# Show form results/submissions on Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, module, admin-panel, adminform

What is the best way to have form results come in row by row into Magento's Admin Panel?

The form results are currently being saved to Magento's database under table name: "my_forms"; the results are also being emailed to me.

**Image #2** shows what my **end result ideally** would look like.  Where the data is being pulled from the database table "my_forms". "my_forms" table has 10 columns:

I assume the steps would be:
**Step 1:** Use php to record form submissions to a new table (my_form) in Magento's database
**Step 2:** Create a new module or modify the "Customers" module?
**Step 3:** Add column names to the module and pull data from the "my_form" table

I've done step 1 successfully but I'm lost on Step 2 and Step 3, or if those are even the right steps to take.  Any advice or direction would be much appreciated!

[image: Current JotForm]

[image: My Ideal Form Example]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom module for this function.

1) Collect the information on the Magento frontend. You can use an already build module to accomplish this task or make one on your own. You will need a custom form and a way to store that data in the Magento database.

2) You will need an interface created in your Magento admin section to display and manage your data. You can use the default Magento Admin grid to accomplish and to have the ability to update the list in bulk and even export the list.

The easiest way to accomplish the above is to search for a Magento Module that already exists and work with it. You will most likely get 99% of your need met.

If that does not work you will need to build this yourself or have a developer do it for you.